# Do gauntlets count as armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monk, armor, barbarian

Do gauntlets count as armor?

Specifically, would wearing Gauntlets of Ogre Power negate the AC bonus that barbarians and monks get because they are technically armor? I feel like they wouldn't.

Answer (score 38):

## The Gauntlets aren't armor

[Every magic item has a category they belong to](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#MagicItemCategories):

> Each magic item belongs to a category: armor, potions, rings, rods, scrolls, staffs, wands, weapons, or wondrous items.
>
> #### Armor
>
> Unless an armor’s description says otherwise, armor must be worn for its magic to function.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Wondrous Items
>
> Wondrous items include worn items such as boots, belts, capes, gloves, and various pieces of jewelry and decoration, such as amulets, brooches, and circlets. Bags, carpets, crystal balls, figurines, horns, musical instruments, and other objects also fall into this catch-all category.

If you look at the [Gauntlets of Ogre Power](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/gauntlets-of-ogre-power), the first line below the item name states:

> *Wondrous Item, uncommon (requires attunement)*

Compare this to the listing for [Armor +1](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/armor-1):

> *Armor (light, medium, or heavy), rare*

If the gauntlets were intended to be treated as armor, they would be in the armor category, not the wondrous items category.